# PHP show records from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Im blocked at following part of code...

i have **config.php** page, with following code inside:

```
<?php
// Start the session (pretty important!)
session_start();

// Establish a link to the database
$dbLink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'USER', 'PASS');
if (!$dbLink) die('Can\'t establish a connection to the database: ' . mysql_error());

$dbSelected = mysql_select_db('DATABASE', $dbLink);
if (!$dbSelected) die ('We\'re connected, but can\'t use the table: ' . mysql_error());

$isUserLoggedIn = false;  
$query      = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE session_id = "' . session_id() . '" LIMIT 1';  
$userResult     = mysql_query($query);  
if(mysql_num_rows($userResult) == 1){  
$_SESSION['user'] = mysql_fetch_assoc($userResult);  
$isUserLoggedIn = true;  
}else{  
if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) != 'index.php'){  
    header('Location: index.php');  
    exit;  
}  
}  
?>
```

Now i have another page, with following code inside:

```
<?php include_once('config.php'); ?>

<?php foreach($_SESSION['user'] as $key => $value){ ?>
<li><?php echo $key; ?> <strong><?php echo $value; ?></strong></li>
<?php } ?>
```

That code show me all informations stored in database, one by one..

I want to show informations, individualy in my page, something like:

```
<?php echo $email; ?>
```

etcetera..

Can someone explain me how to do that?

Thank you

Comment: why not remove some boiler plate from the code above and try to debug the above with something like PHPStorm? Your question would amount to "how do I query a database from php" and google has plenty of those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should output it like

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['email'] ?>
```

assuming that 'email' is the column name in the *users* table.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend.. it's exactly what i want.. Ty !

Answer (score 2):

Just address the relevant field in the associative array:

```
  <?php echo $value['email';?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in the config file:

```
$_SESSION['user']['email'] = mysql_fetch_assoc($userResult);
```

instead of this

```
$_SESSION['user'] = mysql_fetch_assoc($userResult);
```

in your code. You can pass as many columns you want to pass from your table.

And in another page use

```
foreach($_SESSION['user']['email'] as $key => $value)
```

instead of

```
foreach($_SESSION['user'] as $key => $value)
```

in your code.

Remember number of columns you pass in config file, all those columns should be called in this page.